# How to avoid gaps with matplotlib.fill_between and where

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I want to fill the area between two curves but only when the lower curve is >0.
I'm using `fill_between()` in `matplotlib` with a `where` condition (to test which curve is greater) and `numpy.maximum()` (to test whether the lower curve is >0). But there are gaps in the fill because the lower curve crosses the x-axis *between* integers while the result of the `maximum` hits the x-axis *at* an integer. How can I fix this?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0, 10)
a = np.array([101, 102, 71, 56, 49, 15, 29, 31, 45, 41])
b = np.array([52, 39, 8, -7, -12, -45, -23, -9, 14, 19])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, a)
ax.plot(x, b)
ax.fill_between(x, a, np.maximum(b, 0), where=a >= b, alpha=0.25)

plt.axhline(0, color='black')
```

[image]

(I want the white triangles to be shaded as well.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By interpolating values using [`numpy.interp`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0, 10)
a = np.array([101, 102, 71, 56, 49, 15, 29, 31, 45, 41])
b = np.array([52, 39, 8, -7, -12, -45, -23, -9, 14, 19])

x2 = np.linspace(x[0], x[-1] + 1, len(x) * 100)  # <---
a2 = np.interp(x2, x, a)                         # <---
b2 = np.interp(x2, x, b)                         # <---
x, a, b = x2, a2, b2                             # <---

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, a)
ax.plot(x, b)
ax.fill_between(x, a, np.maximum(0, b), where=a>b, alpha=0.25)

plt.axhline(0, color='black')
```

[image: output]

**UPDATE**

```
x2 = np.linspace(x[0], x[-1] + 1, len(x) * 100)
```

should be replaced with:

```
x2 = np.linspace(x[0], x[-1], len(x) * 100)
```

[image: updated output]