# how to color a pyplot polar chart according to its average

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have plotted some data in pyplot polar for classification. The following is one of the images[image]

The classification results is not as expected. Now I want to try to see if I can mark the values above and below the average as shown in the following expected result.
[image]

This is the code for the plot I have for now...

```
theta = np.arange(0, 360 + 360 / 144, 360 / 144) * np.pi / 180
fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8], polar=True)
ax1.set_ylim(0, 4500)
ax1.set_yticks(device_dict[name])
ax1.plot(theta, inter_data)
```

How can I get the desired result?

after plotting according to the answer.
[image]

there are some white spaces in between the color. this is because the next data point does not satisfy the condition, but is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example. You first need to calculate the mean and then make it a vector to plot, then use the `fill_between` function to shade your data like this.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

theta = np.arange(0, 360 + 360 / 144, 360 / 144) * np.pi / 180

#Note that I have to make my own 'inter_data'
inter_data = (theta-np.pi/2.)*np.cos(theta)**2

#Calculate the mean, then multiply by vector of ones with same size as theta
inter_mean = np.nanmean(inter_data)*np.ones(len(theta))


fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
ax1 = fig1.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8], polar=True)

ax1.plot(theta, inter_data,c='C0') #Plot the data

ax1.plot(theta, inter_mean,c='k')   #Plot the mean

#Shade only the positive values where the data is greater than the mean red
ax1.fill_between(theta,inter_data,inter_mean,facecolor='red',alpha=.7,where=(inter_data-inter_mean)>0)

#Shade only the negative values where the data is less than the mean
ax1.fill_between(theta,inter_data,inter_mean,facecolor='yellow',alpha=.7,where=(inter_data-inter_mean)<0)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: this works great, there is a little problem.. please take  a look if you can.. i will edit the question with the new results

Comment: Depending on what your issue/error is, you may need to either provide your data, create a simple example, and/or ask a new question. Also please make sure that your new question cannot be found in another SO question.

Comment: First use a greater than or equal in the where condition for `fill_between`. If that does not help then your issue is because your resolution of theta is not fine enough. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38508556/how-to-avoid-gaps-with-matplotlib-fill-between-and-where

Comment: thanks, i think i am going to have to interpolate the values